# Timeout exception when size of the input to child workflow is huge

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

```
16:37:21.945 [Workflow Executor taskList="PullFulfillmentsTaskList", domain="test-domain": 3] WARN com.uber.cadence.internal.common.Retryer - Retrying after failure
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Request timeout after 1993ms
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.throwOnRpcError(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:546)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.doRemoteCall(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:519)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.respondDecisionTaskCompleted(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:962)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.lambda$RespondDecisionTaskCompleted$11(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:951)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.measureRemoteCall(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:569)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.RespondDecisionTaskCompleted(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:949)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.lambda$sendReply$0(WorkflowWorker.java:301)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.common.Retryer.lambda$retry$0(Retryer.java:104)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.common.Retryer.retryWithResult(Retryer.java:122)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.common.Retryer.retry(Retryer.java:101)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.sendReply(WorkflowWorker.java:301)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handle(WorkflowWorker.java:261)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handle(WorkflowWorker.java:229)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.PollTaskExecutor.lambda$process$0(PollTaskExecutor.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Our parent workflow code is basically like this (`JSONObject` is from org.json)

```java
JSONObject[] array = restActivities.getArrayWithHugeJSONItems();
for(JSONObject hugeJSON: array) {
  ChildWorkflow child = Workflow.newChildWorkflowStub(ChildWorkflow.class);
  child.run(hugeJSON);
}
```

What we find out is that most of the time, the parent workflow worker fails to start the child workflow and throws the timeout exception above. It retries like crazy but never success and print the timeout exception over and over again. However sometimes we got very lucky and it works. And sometimes it fails even earlier at the activity worker, and it throws the same exception. We believe this is due to the size of the data is too big (about 5MB) and could not be sent within the timeout (judging from the log we guess it's set to 2s). If we call `child.run` with small fake data it 100% works.

The reason we use child workflow is we want to use `Async.function` to run them in parallel. So how can we solve this problem? Is there a thrift timeout config we should increase or somehow we can avoid passing huge data around?

Thank you in advance!

---Update after Maxim's answer---

Thank you. I read the example, but still have some questions for my use case. Let's say I got an array of 100 huge JSON objects in my RestActivitiesWorker, if I should not return the huge array to the workflow, I need to make 100 calls to the database to create 100 rows of records and put 100 ids in an array and pass that back to the workflow. Then the workflow create one child workflow per id. Each child workflow then calls another activity with the id to load the data from the DB. But that activity has to pass that huge JSON to the child workflow, is this OK? And for the RestActivitiesWorker making 100 inserts into the DB, what if it failed in the middle?

I guess it boils down to that our workflow is trying to work directly with huge JSON. We are trying to load huge JSON (5-30MB, not that huge) from an external system into our system. We break down the JSON a little bit, manipulate a few values, and use values from a few fields to do some different logic, and finally save it in our DB. How should we do this with Temporal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporal/Cadence doesn't support passing large blobs as inputs and outputs as it uses a DB as underlying storage. So you want to change architecture of your application to avoid this.

The standard workarounds are:

- Use external blob store to save large data and pass reference to it as parameters.
- Cache data in a worker process or even on a host disk and route activities that operate on this data to that process or host. See fileprocessing sample for this approach.